# How to remove ::before from My web app It Does Not ALlow to interact with app

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to remove ::before from my html page it show in body tag not allowing me to interact me with web app . showing in console but no code shows in css files here are the code snippet that show in console

```
body:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2a5555;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking but you could always try and override this CSS... `body:before { content: none !important; }`

Comment: thank you man you solve my problem . You save my day

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
body:before {
    all: initial;
}
```

to put all properties in body:before to their inital value them add your specific rules if you have

```css
body:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2a5555;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 1;
}

body:before {
    all: initial;
   /* other specific rules */
}
```